# what is secure box in smart card and what is role?

Tags: smartcard, javacard

What is secure box in smart card? And any smart card have secure box? What is secure box access control policy? And how do I check the TOE shall explicitly deny access of subjects to objects based on the following additional rules:

> For S.SBNative Code it shall not be possible to perform OP.SB_ACCESS to O.NON_SB_CONTENT
>
> OP.SB_ACCESS : Any read, write or execution access to a memory area
>
> S.SBNative : Is the native code library residing in the Secure Box
>
> O.NON_SB_CONTENT : Any code and data elements not assigned to the native code library residing in the Secure Box

Answer (score 3):

Secure Box is a proprietary feature from NXP JCOP cards to implement native code into Java Card.
CC, TOE and etc are highly specialized topics. If you have any questions about the process of cc-evaluation you should ask your auditor directly.

Comment: What is native code? And how can I use them in my applet? Why they separate it from the EEPROM?

Comment: I haven't done this but afaik its C code. the code must be loaded into eeprom from nxp and you can load it as a library inside your java code